# GWT DataGrid with SimpleLayoutPanel won't present vertical scroll bar

Tags: java, gwt, datagrid

The GWT showcase, as well as many examples I found, there is always a very simple usage of the DataGrid:

1. You define DataGrid element in your UIBinder, and you set it's field to be provided.
2. In the view **constructor** you initialize the grid - define columns **and add data**
3. UI binder is generated
4. Everything it presented as expected..

But the common case is not so static: you usually set up the grid but don't have the data, which may be provided only after the user is doing something (clicking a button, etc).

It took me quite a lot of time to present the DataGrid in my complex UI layout :|
For doing that, the grid is now hosted in SimpleLayoutPanel which has 100% width and height, and this SimpleLayoutPanel is inside some docking panel.
But for reason I don't understand - the grid is displayed beyond the docking panel size, so I can never see the bottom end of its scroll bar.

This is my UI binder (removed some stuff for clarity):

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
    xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">

<ui:style>

.sidePadding {
    padding-left: 8px;
        padding-right: 8px;
 }

    .expanded {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


<g:DockLayoutPanel unit="PX" styleName="{style.expanded}">
    <g:north size="45">
        ...
    </g:north>
    <g:center>
    </g:center>
        ...
    <g:east size="190">
        <g:FlowPanel styleName="{style.sidePadding}">
            <g:FlowPanel>
                <g:Label>SOME TOOLBAR</g:Label>
            </g:FlowPanel>
            <g:HTMLPanel>
                <g:Label>SOME PANEL PANEL </g:Label>
            </g:HTMLPanel>
            <g:FlowPanel ui:field="eastContent">
                <g:Label>SOME FLOW PANEL</g:Label>
            </g:FlowPanel>
            <g:SimpleLayoutPanel ui:field="imagesGrid" addStyleNames="{style.expanded}"/>
        </g:FlowPanel>
    </g:east>
</g:DockLayoutPanel>

</ui:UiBinder>
```

As it turns out - the east panel gets a height of 650px, which is the correct value, but also the DataGrid inside the SimpleLayoutPanel gets the same height! and because there are some labels etc. before it - it overflow the size of the east panel..

Any help???

**UPDATE:**
It seems that if I remove everything from the east-panel and leave only the SimpleLayoutPanel of the DataGrid - it works find!
But I do need to add all those extra labels above the grid - and I can't find a solution.
??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels

Layout panels (`RequiresResize` widgets) have to be nested into other layout panels (`ProvidesResize` widgets) all the way up to either the `RootLayoutPanel`, a `ResizePanel` or a layout panel with an explicit and fixed size (i.e. not *fuild*, e.g. not given in percentage of the parent panel, but rather in pixels).

Here, your `FlowPanel` between the `DockLayoutPanel` and `SimpleLayoutPanel` breaks the hierarchy.

You might want to trade the `FlowPanel` with a `HeaderPanel`, putting all the `FlowPanel`s in the *header* (in a container `FlowPanel`) and your `SimpleLayoutPanel` (or your `Datagrid`) as the *content*.
despite not implementing `ProvidesResize`, `HeaderPanel` respects this contract but for its *content* child only (that's the crux of it: size the *content* child depending on the `HeaderPanel`'s size and the *intrinsic* size of the *header* and *footer*)